# Unable to change angularjs directive template dynamically upon user action

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make an AngularJS directive (my first) with a dynamic template. The idea is simple, it will be a calendar where the user can switch view just like outlook (or insert your favorite calendar here).

I have been trying all manner of compile, template, controller, link that I can find. I am clearly missing something.

I am using an attribute to store the desired time period (so that it may be set in markup by default). A function is called from a button outside the directive which updates the attribute. The attribute updates as expected however I can't figure out how to get the template to re-render.

plnkr provided.

http://plnkr.co/edit/oTE80hMc6DAP7fTmduvo?p=info

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do something like what you are looking for:

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/rGWi9A7z6wa9OrcbReTO?p=preview)

```
angular.module("ngCalendar", [])
    .directive("ngCalendar", function factory() {
        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            replace: true,
            link: function ($scope, element, $attrs) {

   element.html("<div>Please set period attribute.</div>");
   $scope.$watch('canlendarType',function(newValue, oldValue,scope){
       var t = 'sadf';
                switch (newValue) {
                    case 'month':
                        t ="<div>month</div>";
                        break;
                    case 'week':
                        t = "<div>week</div>";
                        break;
                    case 'day':
                        t = "<div>day</div>";
                        break;

        }
        element.html(t);
        });
   }
            }
    });
```